# Is there a way to bypass blogspot's150 post limit?

Tags: limit, blogspot

I currently have published more than 200 posts, but only 153 posts are visible. When I post a new one, older posts disappear.

I have looked for a way to fix the problem, but have not found any definite answer. My research seems to indicate that Blogspot may now limit the number of visible posts to 150, though previously it showed up to 500.

I've tried asking for a listing page using `/feeds/posts/default?max-results=999&start-index=501` to attempt to see more posts by offsetting the start, but they still don't seem to be viewable. Is this an unavoidable platform limitation, or is there a way to see the older posts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Comment: Near as I can tell, this is not blogspot limiting to 150 posts, but blogspot's API will only return 150 results per call, so you need to paginate your calls to get all the results. That's apparently what the `start-index` thing is supposed to do.